# What's up with the background image

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

The background image on the main site:

[image: background]

It seems to have developed a very subtle "pixelation" effect.

Here is enlarged, contrast-enhanced version of the image, making it plainer:

“Enlarge and enhance”

[image: Enhance]

Is this intentional or is it the result of some weird compression artifact?

Comment: Nothing's changed to bg-site.jpg since the new design was launched. did you notice this recently?

Comment: Where exactly did you take that screenshot? I've checked the main site, nothing seems wrong. I've checked some quotes inside a question topic, nothing seems wrong.